# When user input emoji into EditText, it's count like 2 symbols. How to count emoji like 1 symbol?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have InputEditText from Google Material. And when I enter emoji from soft keyboard, on counter instead of 1 symbol shows 2 symbols per emoji. How to avoid it and count emoji like 1 symbol?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/optionalInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_default_vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="@string/spend_visit_note"
    app:counterEnabled="false"
    app:counterMaxLength="100"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/optionalEditText"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Widget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="101"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
optionalEditText
    .afterTextChangeEvents()
    .skipInitialValue()
    .throttleFirst(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    .map {
        Action.OptionalEdited(
            it.editable?.toString() ?: String.empty
        )
    }
    .bindToUiActions()
```

I try to find smth in methods or documentation, but I found nothing